# sql server profiler: How to know which db is being hit using sql server profiler

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 application, connected to 2 different databases on one instance.

I am trying to trace some functionality using SQL Server Profiler(Standard Template) but difficult to understand which database is being hit by one application just by looking into the trace.

Kindly suggest how to know the dbname being hit by one application.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to filter by each database name.

Under Trace properties > Events Selection tab > select Show all columns. 
You should see the database name under column filters. 
Enter the database name for the Like section and you should see traces only for that database.

You can also read more about this [here](http://blog.thekfactor.info/posts/ms-sql-profiler-limiting-trace-information-by-database-name/)

Comment: Thanks Henrik for your suggestion. But when i am selecting "Events Selection tab > select Show all columns" i can not see Database Name option instead ApplicationName option is available in Standard Tamplete. Kindly suggest if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Standard template is default. Which version of sql profiler are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 Profiler Developer Edition. In Standard template, DatabaseName filter is not available. However, i can see DatabaseName under Tuning template

Answer (score 2):

Use standard template (Default)
And you should see it.

[image]